# Connection timed out Hive on Spark EMR

Tags: apache-spark, hive, amazon-emr

I am using AWS EMR to set up Hive on Spark. I have Hive 3.1.3 and Spark 3.4.0 (EMR version emr-6.12.0). When I run a query and check the hive logs, I see -

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for client connection.
        at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.RpcServer$2.run(RpcServer.java:172)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:120)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I have `hive.spark.client.connect.timeout` and `hive.spark.client.server.connect.timeout` set to 5 seconds.

I have followed the steps mentioned here - https://mryangli.com/2021/01/10_hive-with-spark-on-aws-emr/
Can anyone guide me as to what I might be missing?

Comment: Why do you need the old init script? just check the hive and spark, run the emr and do what you want then it should work.